# How to use Roboto condesed (or thin) font in ICS+?

Tags: android, fonts

I can't find the way to set Roboto condensed (thin) instead of the default one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 18):

1. Download the full [Roboto](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) family
2. Copy `Roboto-Condensed.ttf` into your project's `assets` folder
3. In code, get a reference to your `Typeface` with `Typeface robotoCond = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Condensed.ttf")`
4. Use this in any widget, e.g. `textView.setTypeface(robotoCond);`
5. ???
6. PROFIT!

Comment: This works for the application. But I forgot I'd have also to use it inside an homescreen Widget. There I run in the homescreen process and I've no access to my assets folder to summon the Font. And in the homescreen widget I can't use a custom TextView with the condensed font in it.
Is there any way to use it inside an homescreen widget? 
The font is in the system/font folder, so why do I have to put the ttf file inside my asset folder instead of using the system one?

Comment: In Jelly Beans the condensed font is present (not in ICS as I previousely said), but in API 16 they didn't upgrade the enums for the  android:typeface attribute, so the sans-serif-condensed is not available via XML. So I can natively use the Typeface inside my application, but not in the homescreen widget. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: From what I understand there's no way to use a custom font in a widget. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4318572/321697) has some workaround answers that you may find useful.

Comment: Can't we use it without importing? I mean come on, It's ICS/JB. It should be already available... :/

Comment: @kcoppock - Thankyou! That's what I was looking for. Another short question; How to use them in webview (in ICS+)?

Comment: @SheharyarNaseer I have near-zero experience with WebViews -- this looks like what you need, though: http://droidista.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-custom-font-in-webview.html

Comment: @kcoppock - But that's the thing, I want to do it without importing Roboto into my assets. That should be possible in Android 4.0.0 onwards. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help. Cheers! :D