# How to determine the TextView width in a Widget?

Tags: android

When I looked solutions:

[How to use a custom typeface in a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318572/how-to-use-a-custom-typeface-in-a-widget)

**In the above problem, I use a custom font in a Widget;
The use of solution:**

```
public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time) 
  {
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 84, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"Clockopia.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(clock);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(65);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    myCanvas.drawText(time, 80, 60, paint);
    return myBitmap;
  }
```

**Question：How to determine the width and height of the bitmap generated according to the number of characters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(time, 0, time.length(), rect); // time = your text
int w = rect.width(); // width text
int h = rect.height(); // height of text
```

This will save the bounds of your text in a Rect and then you can measure the Rect.

Comment: I need to increase the width and height so that the font can be displayed properly-->int widthOffset = Utils.dip2px(context, 12); int heightOffset = Utils.dip2px(context, 3); Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rect.width(), size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);