# How to change TextView font face in Widget

Tags: android, widget, font-face

I'M trying to write a widget. There ise a linear layout and textview in activity. I want to show remaining time with textview. And I want to change my widget's font-face.

I successed to change Imageview's font-face, but when I'm trying to change textview font-face, I'm getting an error.

My Code:

```
 Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
 Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Harngton.ttf");
 paint.setTypeface(font);
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 paint.setTextSize(12);
 myCanvas.drawText("MUSTAFA", 10, 20, paint);
 try {
   Log.d("DEBUG_LOG","Before.....");
   remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.label, myBitmap);
   Log.d("DEBUG_LOG","After......");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.d("DEBUG_LOG","Error message:" + e.getMessage());
}

Log.d("DEBUG_LOG","Hello! Outside try catch");
```

Error Log:

```
03-29 20:41:49.651: D/DEBUG_LOG(21519): Before.....
03-29 20:41:49.651: D/DEBUG_LOG(21519): After......
03-29 20:41:49.651: D/DEBUG_LOG(21519): Hello! Outside try catch
03-29 20:41:56.591: D/DEBUG_LOG(21519): Before.....
03-29 20:41:56.591: D/DEBUG_LOG(21519): After......
03-29 20:41:56.591: D/DEBUG_LOG(21519): Hello! Outside try catch
```

And "problem loading widget" is writing in widget area.

Tried:
http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2012/09/android-textview-with-custom-font-support/ - yes, it was worked in normal activity but not in widget activity :S

and this code;

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Harngton.ttf");

paint.setTypeface(font);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(12);
myCanvas.drawText("MUSTAFA", 30, 20, paint);

remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.txtTime, myBitmap);
```

this code is changing imageview's font-face but I'M getting an error with textview.

Best Regards..

Comment: I edited my post. And posted error log.

Comment: [That may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318572/how-to-use-a-custom-typeface-in-a-widget) I made it by that question