# Custom font in TextView

Tags: android, view, fonts

I have been making a Digital Clock App Widget, and I have a font I'd like to use, however I can not make a custom View. Tried it, seems like it is not intended to work in a widget(I found out later that I can't use custom views in widgets). And I would really like to have that font, any suggestions?

Comment: What widget is it that you're trying to use?

Comment: Wait what?! I am making a widget, and I need to implement my custom TextView.

Comment: Found answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318572/how-to-use-a-custom-typeface-in-a-widget