# Setting custom font on widget remote view is not working

Tags: android, widget, android-remoteview

I am using following line of code to set custom font on widget using `remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.folder_widget_text_view, SS);`but its not working at all, If i used the same code on normal `TextView.setText(SS)` method it works.

So is anything wrong in my code or if I miss something.

```
SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("hello");
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan(this, "Rosemary.ttf"), 0, SS.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.folder_widget_text_view, SS);
```

**CustomTypefaceSpan Class**

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan 
{
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
            new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

    private Typeface mTypeface;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) 
    {
        mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

        if (mTypeface == null) 
        {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), typefaceName);

            // Cache the loaded Typeface
            sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) 
    {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) 
    {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318572/how-to-use-a-custom-typeface-in-a-widget

Comment: I know using bitmap it is possible, but it won't give me correct result in all device. So I need better solution other then that.

Comment: @AndroidDev how can i fix this problem?