# Android app widget, custom fonts

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget, custom-font, android-fonts

I have a question about widgets in android. I've created a simple digital clock with appWidgetProvider using TextClock. My question is if there's an option to use a custom font for TextClock. I used android: fontfamily, but  i don't want to use default fonts.

Comment: If TextClock is the subclass of TextView then you can use it. Please check and update the post

Comment: Check this out https://youtu.be/7kD0ZYzJbYo

Comment: The answer I found when looking at this previously was using Bitmap and drawing text with custom typeface into it. In my case, I have decided to just forget about custom font on a widget, as the fonts were not essential for me at the time. However, it is something you could look at. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411060/1615525

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not strictly with `TextClock`. You have no way to configure a `RemoteViews` to use a custom `Typeface` for anything, let alone a `TextClock`.