# How to use Custom Font in Android Widget?

Tags: android, widget

Well, I'm making one Android app which can display Time and Date in App Widget(in HomeScreen).

I Loaded my Font under **Assets -> Fonts**.
Even after trying with FontFamily it doesn't work.

I'm sure font family doesn't work in widgets. I don't have any idea about this.

Thanks for your Help :)

Comment: By "Widget", do you mean an [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview)?

Comment: Yes, Buddy. App Widgets Only

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot use custom fonts with app widgets.

Comment: Oh No !! I found some apps are using Custom Fonts in App Widgets :( No Possible ways?

Comment: Perhaps they are using bitmaps and `ImageView`, rather than `TextView`.

Comment: Actually, I need to Display a Clock with Custom Font :( Found this Thread. Seems it's not working. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4318572/4025157

Comment: That is the approach that I suggested. If you are running into problems, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] and an explanation of what is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Setting fontFamily in a homescreen widget layout file, like this

```
android:fontFamily="@font/cherry_swash"
```

does correctly display a custom font in homescreen widget TextViews with Android O and P, but not with earlier versions.

Comment: Not working for Google Pixel Android 12